# OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() raises InvalidOperationException in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

Below is my code snippet.

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx;*.xls;)|*.xlsx;*.xls;",
};

if (dialog.ShowDialog().Value == false)
{
    IsCommiting = false;
    return;
}
else
{
    Items.Clear();
}
```

When dialog.ShowDialog() called, InvalidOperationException was raised with this message "ShowDialog failed.".

I've found a related article by google search.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightmvvm/thread/6ae9454b-b5ba-4286-959f-6dc4d347ebf7/

This article is about multi-selection in open file dialog. But I didn't set Multiselect property to True. This problem doesn't happen often, and cannot be reproduced.

Is there anyone who suffered from same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
{    
     Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx,*.xls)|*.xlsx,*.xls"
};

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == false)
{
    IsCommiting = false;
    return;
}
else
{
    Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() returns Nullable<bool>. If return value is not null, this code is same with mine. I think it is not solution. Or could you give me more explanation?

Comment: There is a limit on the time allowed between when the user initiates the dialog and when the dialog is shown. Are you execute other code before calling `ShowDialog` ? <= Ok no... it raise `SecurityException`

Answer (score 0):

Though it may sound a bit strange - since OpenFileDialog actually opens an Explorer window (which executes shell extensions), have you considered, disabling all shell extensions by [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
```